# The prop object's property is undefined in refresh function

Tags: vue.js

I use Vue.js and have a component. I pass a prop "request" to that component:

```
<adjustments-list
  v-if="request"
  :request="request"
/>
```

In the component I'm able to do this:

```
<text-input
  :value="request.id"
/>
```

It works that is the value of "id" is displayed.

In props section of component:

```
props: {
  request: Object
```

In mounted hook of component:

```
async mounted () {
  await this.refresh()
},
```

In refresh function of component:

```
async refresh () {
  console.log('this.request.id =', this.request.id)
  if (this.request.id) {
    const data = await requestApi.getRequestResultAdjustmentByReqId(this.request.id)
  }
},
```

The this.request.id is undefined.

I'm not sure why.

Comment: request property is being pass from parent component? I think when the subcomponent is just 'mounted' the property has not ye been initialized or something.

Comment: Yes. The request property has been passed from parent component. But, how to make it work?

Comment: maybe you can add a 'watch' for that property and go from there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `request` property is asynchronously available to the component then, you have to use combination of watchers like:

```
// adjustments-list component
new Vue({

  props: {
    request: Object
  },

  data() {
    return {
      apiData: null
    }
  },

  watch: {
    request(newValue, _oldValue) {
      this.refresh(newValue);
    }
  },

  mounted: function () {
    // Do something here
  },

  methods: {

    refresh (request) {
      if (request.id) {
        // Using promise instead of async-await
        requestApi.getRequestResultAdjustmentByReqId(request.id)
          .then(() => this.apiData = data);
      }
    }

  }
});
```

Also, note that, `mounted` should be a plain old JS function and not an `async` function. That's the lifecycle method of the component supposed to behave in particular way.